# `Advice.WithCustomMapping` to bind a dynamically added field

Tags: java, byte-buddy

Using `byte-buddy`, I think I need to use `Advice.WithCustomMapping` to reference arbitrary fields that I choose based on some runtime logic.

However, I am a little lost how to create a reference to fields that I add as part of instrumentation?

```
AgentBuilder ab = new AgentBuilder.Default();
...
ab = ab.type(named(type))
       .transform((builder, td, _cl, _m) ->
          builder
             .defineField("$lat$", LatencyEvent.class, Visibility.PUBLIC) // new field; I want to create multiple
             .visit(Advice.withCustomMapping()
             .bind(Lat.class, td.getDeclaredFields().filter(named("$lat$")).getOnly()) // ok, here I want to reference the newly added field
             .to(EndLatAdvice.class)
             .on(isMethod().and(named(until)))) // pick a target method
...
private static class EndLatAdvice {
      @Advice.OnMethodEnter
      static void enter(@Lat LatencyEvent l) { // hoping to have access to the newly added field
...
}
```

Also, while we are at it, I notice for `Advice.FieldValue` we need to specify `readOnly = false`, if we mean to write back to that field. How is that done for the `WithCustomMapping` (assuming that's the right tool for this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would supply an instance of `Advice.OffsetMapping` where you have the instrumented type with all fields supplied as a parameter value.

From that mapping, you would return an instance of `Advice.OffsetMapping.Target.ForField.ReadWrite` for this field, unless you have something custom to apply.

Comment: Thanks. I am intrigued about "something custom to apply", and about a constructor with `StackManipulator`. I get a feeling that `StackManipulator` can do something to the value after extracting it from the field. Is that right? (Is there comprehensive documentation about these cool things that I am missing? Trawling javadocs is not an easy task)

Comment: Custom as in custom code. A stack manipulation only collects byte code instructions. If you know a byte code tutorial, it will make sense to you.

Comment: Thanks. I was more concerned that I may use a thing whose behaviour will change in the future, or maybe a simpler path exists. I ended up implementing `Target`, although bumped my head a few times on the way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured out two ways. Would be great to hear which one may be considered "canonical".

1. Create another `AgentBuilder` which only creates the fields:

```
AgentBuilder addField = new AgentBuilder.Default();
AgentBuilder ab = new AgentBuilder.Default();
...
addField = addField.type(named(type))
       .transform((builder, td, _cl, _m) ->
          builder
             .defineField("$lat$", LatencyEvent.class, Visibility.PUBLIC))
ab = ab.type(named(type))
       .transform((builder, td, _cl, _m) ->
          builder
             .visit(Advice.withCustomMapping()
             .bind(Lat.class, td.getDeclaredFields().filter(named("$lat$")).getOnly()) // ok, this one now finds the field
             .to(EndLatAdvice.class)
             .on(isMethod().and(named(until)))) // pick a target method
...
     addField.with(AgentBuilder.TypeStrategy.Default.REDEFINE)
        .ignore(none())
        .installOn(inst);

      ab.with(AgentBuilder.TypeStrategy.Default.REDEFINE)
        .ignore(none())
        .installOn(inst);
```

Now there are two agents, one is three to simply create fields, the second one re-redefines the same classes, and by the time it is run, it can see the fields created by `addField`. I wonder if the order of execution is guaranteed.

2. Create `Latent` references to fields instead of looking up by name.

```
TypeDescription.Generic latField = new TypeDescription.Generic.OfNonGenericType.ForLoadedType(LatencyEvent.class);
...
ab = ab.type(named(type))
       .transform((builder, td, _cl, _m) ->
          builder
             .defineField("$lat$", LatencyEvent.class, Visibility.PUBLIC) // new field; I want to create multiple
             .visit(Advice.withCustomMapping()
             .bind(Lat.class, new FieldDescription.Latent(td, "$lat$", 1, latField, List.of())) // ok, we can reference the field by name
             .to(EndLatAdvice.class)
             .on(isMethod().and(named(until)))) // pick a target method
```

This one works with just one Agent.

### But this is a read-only reference - cannot write back to the field.

In order to write, need to reference slightly differently:

3. Same as (2) above, except `bind` for `Lat.class` annotation should be:

```
...
.bind(Lat.class, new Advice.OffsetMapping.ForField.Unresolved.WithImplicitType(latField, false, Assigner.Typing.STATIC, "$lat$"))
...
```

So, still a `bind`, just need a `ForField...WithImplicitType` instead of a `Latent` reference.